# How to select whole words from a string that appears in an array?

Tags: ruby

I want check a long string against array of words and select the matching words.  The words could be multi-words `such as` or `This is` or more.  This is what I have so far.

```
str = "This is a demo text for demo..."
w = ["This is", "to", "is", "for demo"]     
w.select{ |w| str.include?w } #=>["This is", "is", "for demo"]
```

but in this I don't want my result to have "in", "get" etc

```
str = "This is a demo text for demo together within..."
w = ["This is", "to", "is", "for demo", "in", "get"]    
w.select{ |w| str.include?w } #=> ["This is", "to", "is", "for demo", "in", "get"]
```

`str.include?w` is doing what it is supposed to do. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: try w.select{ |w1| str.include?(w1 + " ") }

Comment: That's not enough, Alok.  SO wants 'in' excluded when `str = '...within the...'` and included when `str = '...jumped in'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = "This is a demo text for demo..."
w = ["This is", "to", "is", "for demo"]     
p w.select{|w|str =~ /\b#{w}\b/ }
```

The \b in the regexp is a word boundary; the #{w} is interpolation, just like in strings.

Comment: @cary Swoveland perfect answer sir

Comment: This is so neat! very beautiful!